# Is it possible to use comments in virsh / libvirt xml files?

Tags: libvirt, virsh

I am using.

```
virsh -c qemu:///system edit VM-Name
```

And adding comments.

```
<!-- test comment here -->
```

It won't complain.* But the comment is removed.

*Usually if you make a syntax error (for example add an extra `>`) somewhere), it says something like this.

```
error: (domain_definition):75: Extra content at the end of the document
>
^
 Failed. Try again? [y,n,f,?]:
```

Is there any way to preserve comments in `virsh` / `libvirt` `xml` files?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that now you can, copy your xml file somewhere, tell virsh to use it :

```
virsh define ~/vm.xml
```

and comment what you want.

When you launch the vm, virsh will make a copy of the file in `/etc/libvirt`, remove comments there and start the vm, thus not touching your original xml file `/etc/libvirt`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<metadata comment="This is a comment"/>
```

Tested on CentOS 8 Stream with:
`virsh --version`
4.5.0

Comment: This does not work on `virsh 4.0.0`